# Livelink LAPI to Content Server web service

Tags: livelink

currently working on a project upgrading from livelink LAPI to Content Server web service. I wonder if there is some sort of API mapping document out there to convert from LAPI to web service call.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer this question, but hoping this may help someone in future.

You can find the LAPI and CWS documentation and code samples at OpenText Knowledge Center

[Livelink Application Programming Interface (LAPI)](https://knowledge.opentext.com/knowledge/llisapi.dll/fetch/16060242/llesapi/v090701/llesapi-pgd/en/html/_manual.htm)

[Content Web Services Home](https://knowledge.opentext.com/knowledge/llisapi.dll?func=ll&objId=45500683&objAction=browse&viewType=1)

[Content Web Service Java API References](https://knowledge.opentext.com/knowledge/llisapi.dll?func=ll&objId=45500683&objAction=browse&viewType=1)